# Python script for downloading data from instrument internal memory through browser

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, scrapy, communication

I have to download data from an instrument by connecting LAN wire directly. After that I have to open the web browser and log into instrument Settings by entering a particular IP address.
Eventhough there are lots of tabs and options,I have to download the data by inputing  day wise by inputing start date and end date in a particular tab,

How to automate this process by python?
Which libraries should I import ?

Answer (score 1):

Use your web browser dev tools to inspect the HTTP requests that your browser does during the manual process, and automate it with [Requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) if you don’t need multiple downloads in parallel, or [Scrapy](https://scrapy.readthedocs.io/) otherwise.